# How to get whole number rating in custom ratingbar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am geting the decimal values like 1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,etc...,when i clicks the stars

How to get whole number rating in custom ratingbar?

Is it Possible?

ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener()

```
{

    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser)
    {   

        Toast.makeText(Rating.this, "New Rating: " + rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    }});
}
```

Comment: why you cant convert that float to int value like int r = (int)rating;

Comment: Adding these two, android:stepSize="1.0" and int r = (int)rating; myself getting 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Do you mean ratingBar.getMax()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use attribute `android:stepSize="1.0"`